# Why Are My Event Reminders Not Being Sent?

Tags: drupal, scheduled-reminders

I should have received an event reminder I had scheduled to go out today, but didn't.

I have confirmed that the email was saved under the "schedule reminders" tab of the event.

I did notice that it didn't appear on the scheduled mailings here - /civicrm/mailing/browse/scheduled (but I'm still new to civi so not sure if they're supposed to show there or not).

I don't think I have configured everything for bulk mailing properly yet, but some emails do go out (like registration or membership confirmations).

Drupal 7.38
civiCRM 4.4.15

Comment: Ashe - it helps if you can feedback on answers or accept them

Comment: sorry, I got pulled away by other projects.  just now coming back to this.

Comment: Scheduled Reminders are not using CiviMail, so the tag you used here may be misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Is your Scheduled Jobs for Send Scheduled Reminders enabled at civicrm/admin/job?reset=1 ? If so, does the View Log Job have any info? /civicrm/admin/joblog?jid=8&reset=1.

If not, and if you want to confirm if your cron is running, then enable a Scheduled Job and then check back later, when it should have run, and see what the Scheduled Job shows as the last time it ran. If it hasn't run then you probably need to check your cron set up http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Managing+Scheduled+Jobs

Comment: Send Scheduled Reminders was not enabled.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: test email still didn't send. I set the run frequency to run every hour and scheduled an email to send at the top of the hour, but it didn't go out. I do see the email in scheduled mails.

Comment: Are you confusing Scheduled Reminders, with CiviMails. They are different. They each have a Scheduled Job that triggers them. There needs to be a cron running to implement these.

Comment: I assumed that testing a scheduled email would give me some idea of whether or not the new settings would help.

Comment: added some info to answer to help if you need to check if you cron is running. hth